# Swift: Restrict access to specific frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, module, frameworks

I am working on a group of frameworks. All of them have their public interface but I want to restrict some method being called by other apps or frameworks than the members of this group.
So I'd like to define some kind of custom access level between public and internal, visible only for specific frameworks. The frameworks are distributed by Cocoapods and they supposed to be dynamically linked. Does anyone have idea how to achieve this?

Comment: How about passing some secret api key from the caller (using a setter or a method argument) so that only if the caller passes the correct key the method is executed?

Comment: The problem is that I want to achieve this in compile time or link time if possible.

Comment: So the solution is a linker setting called "Dynamic Library Allowable Clients" where you can enumerate which libraries allowed your framework link with.